# transliterate from IPA to Roman alphabet

Tags: english, phonetics, ipa, transcription

I'm trying to figure out what is this in Roman Alphabet

> ʔə ʤoʷk
>
> (ʔə ˈmɛ ɹə ˌkʰɪn):        seʲ, wʌʦ jɹ̩ ʤɐːb?
>
> (ˈʔɪ̃ŋ gɫɪʃ mə̃n):            ʔɐ̃͡ɪ mə kʰlaːk.
>
> (ʔə ˈmɛ ɹə ˌkʰɪn):        jə mĩʲn jə goʷ tʰɪk-tʰɐk ʔɔɫ deʲ?
>
> ɐ̃͡ɪ mə kʰlaːk

Comment: This depends of course on what language this is... I can see it's English, but different languages, different spelling rules. There is no unique Roman transcription for IPA symbols since IPA is there *because* the Latin alphabet is not sufficient to uniquely represent all the phomemes that are attempted to be uniquely mapped in IPA, so the representation in Roman letters will of course highly depend on the individual language's spelling rules.

Comment: Lemontree, thank you, thank you so much !!!!!!!  This is a huge help!!

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to do this, thanks again Lemontree

Comment: I tried to find an online tool that does this for a [question on Language Learning SE](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/861/800). I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A joke
>
> (American) Say, what's your job?
>
> (Englishman) I'm a clerk ("clock").
>
> (American) You mean you go 'tick-tock' all day?
>
> (Englishman) I'm a clerk ("clock").

The joke about it is that UK *clerk* sounds like US *clock* (= kʰlaːk), that's probably why it's written in IPA because the joke doesn't work with Roman letters.